# How to access Collider in c# script with its tag name

Tags: unity, 2d, monodevelop

[image]I want to access a Collider in c# script file with its tag name 
I Tried this

```
if (Collider2D == Physics2D.OverlapPoint(touchPos))
{
    Some Code to be Performed
}
```

I want to access this Collider2D with its Tag Name like this

```
if (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("tag name") == Physics2D.OverlapPoint(touchPos))
{
    Some Code to be Performed
}
```

But Its not working 
Please Help...

```
public GameObject[] targets,targetss;

    void Start () {
        targets = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("right screen");
        targetss = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("left screen");
    }


    void Update () {
        if (Input.touches.Length <= 0) {

        } else {
            Vector3 wp = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
            Vector2 touchPos = new Vector2(wp.x, wp.y);

            foreach(GameObject target in targets)
            {
                if (target.collider2D == Physics2D.OverlapPoint(touchPos))
                {

                    GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("player2").transform.position = 
                    new Vector2(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("player2").transform.position.x, wp.y);

                }
            }


            foreach(GameObject target in targetss)
            {
                if (target.collider2D == Physics2D.OverlapPoint(touchPos))
                {

                    GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("player1").transform.position = 
                    new Vector2(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("player1").transform.position.x, wp.y);

                }
            }





        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Stated that your examples clearest statement is "Some Code to be Performed" ...
You must do some things:

Not confuse [classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming)) with [objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_(computer_science))

Search all objects ( istance not class) like this

```
public GameObject[] targets;
targets = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("tagName");

foreach (GameObject target in target) {
// get collider of each object
       if (target.collider!= null){
           if (target.collider.OverlapPoint(touchPos)){
              //Some Code to be Performed
           }
       }
}
```

Comment: actually I have two colliders and have to perform tasks accordingly when touches performs on each collider.

Comment: I suggest you editing your question integrating the additional information. That may help people to target your problem

Comment: please have a look now on updated question ! actually touch on collider is working but single touch at a time i want to move both sliders on single time that's why i have devided screen in two parts with 2 box collider but i am unable to move both colliders at a time...... please have a look on attached image to understand actual issue ... in image i want to move both the slider with both hands at a single time as this game is for android mobiles

Answer (score 0):

There is something to correct, in my humble opinion..

When you do

```
public GameObject[] targets,targetss;
    void Start () {
            targets = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("right screen");
            targetss = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("left screen");
        }
```

parhaps you should do instead

```
public GameObject targets,targetss;
void Start () {
        targets = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("right screen");
        targetss = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("left screen");
    }
```

just because I assume you want to have ONE collider per side.

Then would be interesting to understand what you want to achieve.
Here I assume again you want the circle to detect collision with side bars.

If the circle is moved with physics you should add to the side bars an

> OnCollisionEnter2D(Collider2D coll)

function to describe what is to be done when collisions occur.